# Invalid Choice Error Using Dynamic Choice Assignment in a form

Tags: django-forms

I have built a form which takes a dynamic list of choices by overriding the form's `__init`__ method.

```
class AssociateSfnForm(forms.Form):

    chosen_sfns = forms.ChoiceField(label='', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)


def __init__(self, sfn_choices, *args, **kwargs):

    super(AssociateSfnForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['chosen_sfns'].choices = sfn_choices

    print self.fields['chosen_sfns'].choices
```

Everything works except that I keep getting a validation error stating that the choice is not valid. In my view I set the list of choices prior to testing for validation of the form:

```
def manually_match_sfns(request, cgs335_id):

    cgs335 = get_object_or_404(Cgs335, pk=cgs335_id)

    # number of SFNs to bring back and display to the user
    number = 10
    sfn_choices = get_sfn_choices(cgs335.aircraft, cgs335.flying_date, number)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = AssociateSfnForm(sfn_choices, request.POST )

        if form.is_valid():
            --- processing here ----

    else:
        form = AssociateSfnForm(sfn_choices)

    extra_context = {}

    extra_context.update({'cgs335': cgs335})
    extra_context.update({'form': form})

    return render(request, 'sumdata/manually_match_sfns.html', extra_context)
```

When debugging this problem, I check the form.fields['chosen_sfns'].choices and each time they are the same but the is_valid() method throws a validation error.

Choices before page loads...

```
-> return render(request, 'sumdata/manually_match_sfns.html', extra_context)
(Pdb) form.fields['chosen_sfns'].choices
[('149907AUT_26/03/13 15:28:37', '149907AUT_26/03/13 15:28:37 -- 2013-03-26 12:34:02 -- Debrief #1 Post RON Entered By XXXXXX From CGS335# 13103'), ..., ('Irreconcilable', 'Irreconcilable -- Do not try to associate again.'), ('Not Associated', 'Not Associated -- Come back to this one later')]
```

Choices prior to validation...

```
-> if form.is_valid():
(Pdb) form.fields['chosen_sfns'].choices
[('149907AUT_26/03/13 15:28:37', '149907AUT_26/03/13 15:28:37 -- 2013-03-26 12:34:02 -- Debrief #1 Post RON Entered By XXXXXX From CGS335# 13103'), ..., ('Irreconcilable', 'Irreconcilable -- Do not try to associate again.'), ('Not Associated', 'Not Associated -- Come back to this one later')]
```

I selected Irreconcilable and got the following error message:
    Select a valid choice. [u'Irreconcilable'] is not one of the available choices.

I am at a loss as to why the error is raised since "Irreconcilable" is clearly in the list of choices in each case.

If anybody can see what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate them pointing it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mismatch between the field type and the widget. I wanted multiple selection.

Change:

```
chosen_sfns = forms.ChoiceField(label='', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

To:

```
chosen_sfns = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```